# Group by giving null values for not null field

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table as follows

```
id name tid seq aname ds
1  a     xy  10  G     E
1  a     xz  20  G     E
1  a     az  30  G     E
1  b     wq  10  G     E
1  b     as  20  G     E
2  c     qw  10  G     E
2  c     sd  20  G     E  
1  a     fg  34  S     F
```

Now i want the o/p as follows

```
id name tid seq  
1  a    az  30

1  b    as  20       
2  c    sd  20
```

My query is as follows

```
select id,name,tid,max(seq) 
from table 
group by id,name where aname='G' and ds='E';
```

But iam getting null values in tid field.Where did i go wrong?Please help.Thank you

Comment: sorry to say but where is the primary key in your table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this is by using a subquery which gets the maximum `seq` for every group of `ID` and `Name`. The result of the subquery is then joined back on the table itself provided that it match on three columns: `ID`, `Name`, and `seq`, to give you the correct value of `tid`.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  id, name, max(seq) max_seq
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP   BY ID,name 
        ) b ON a.ID = b.ID AND
                a.seq = b.max_seq AND
                a.name = b.name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bc36d/3)

OUTPUT

```
╔════╦══════╦═════╦═════╗
║ ID ║ NAME ║ TID ║ SEQ ║
╠════╬══════╬═════╬═════╣
║  1 ║ a    ║ az  ║  30 ║
║  1 ║ b    ║ as  ║  20 ║
║  2 ║ c    ║ sd  ║  20 ║
╚════╩══════╩═════╩═════╝
```

Comment: I have some additional conditions which i mentioned using where clause at the end of the query

Comment: then what happens when you execute the query?

Comment: are you sure the records given above, somewhat the same as your records on the db? maybe you have missed something.

Comment: yea..apart from those there are many other fields in which iam not interested but the above mentioned rows were retrieved from the table depending on some conditions that i mentioned in the where clause..